# Determine the camera vector in openGL

Tags: opengl, vector, camera, lwjgl

What I'm doing right now is designing a flight simulator of some kind. What I want to know is how I can determine/extract/calculate the camera vector in OpenGL i.e. I want to know the vector which describes the direction the camera is facing.

What I want to do, for example is to simulate a barrel roll. How I thought I could do this is to use the following code:

```
GL11.glRotatef(raw, vector_x, vector_y, vector_z);
```

I, however can't figure out how to extract the camera vector.

BTW, I'm using LWJGL and GLApp.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Z (or -Z, depending your matrices handedness) axis of the camera's transformation matrix.